# add category to url for only posts of particular category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, posts

I am aware that I can change the url structure using `/%category%/%postname%/` to show the category in the url but I only want this effect for posts with category = `'Articles'`.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin for that, try [redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) or [custom-post-type-permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)

Comment: If you want change permalink without plugin, check [this link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy/188834)